# I cant handle RecyclerView onClick events in A fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have a problem handling simple code on onClick events in my recycler view. Is the error on where i put the onClick event? How do I fix it and why does it happen? Is there any logical mistakes in this? Please tell me everything.
BTW I have tried running several kinds of simple code to test the onClick event and none of them have worked.
Here is my adapter java class

```html
package co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.Gallery;
import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.MainActivity;
import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.R;
import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.clases.PersonajeVo;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

/**
 * Created by CHENAO on 13/07/2017.
 */

public class PersonajesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonajesAdapter.PersonajeViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<PersonajeVo> listaPersonaje;
    private Context mContext;

    public PersonajesAdapter(ArrayList<PersonajeVo> listaPersonaje) {
        this.listaPersonaje=listaPersonaje;
        ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String>mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public PersonajeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);
        return new PersonajeViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonajeViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.txtNombre.setText(listaPersonaje.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.txtInformacion.setText(listaPersonaje.get(position).getInfo());
        holder.txtInformacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaPersonaje.size();
    }

    public class PersonajeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtNombre,txtInformacion;
        ImageView foto;

        public PersonajeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtNombre= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNombre);
            txtInformacion= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idInfo);
            foto= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagen);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Position of the click listener is fine. I don't see where you set the value of mContext.

Comment: in your PersonajesAdapter constructor, add Context as an argument and provide the context from where you call the adapter.

Comment: CAn you explain to me how to do that? Im new here haha

Comment: Do you call the adapter `new PersonajesAdapter(listaPersonajes)` from the Activity class? (the one that extends AppCompatActivity). If yes, then you need to change `public PersonajesAdapter(ArrayList<PersonajeVo> listaPersonaje)` to `public PersonajesAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<PersonajeVo> listaPersonaje)`, and add `mContext=c;` to the constructor where you have `this.listaPersonaje=listaPersonaje;`. Then, you need to change `new PersonajesAdapter(listaPersonajes)` in the activity class to `new PersonajesAdapter(this, listaPersonajes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your `mContext`, you declare it but not set any value, so please update your constructor as below

```
public PersonajesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PersonajeVo> listaPersonaje) {
        this.listaPersonaje = listaPersonaje;
        this.mContext = context;
        ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Comment: Now i get an error inmy list fragment right here PersonajesAdapter adapter=new PersonajesAdapter(listaPersonaje);

Comment: edit it as  PersonajesAdapter adapter=new PersonajesAdapter(getContext(),listaPersonaje);